# PYTHONPATH does not seem to be used

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, ubuntu-13.10

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

1) `vi /home/user/.profile` shows

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user/folder/script/_lib/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

2) `printenv` shows

```
PYTHONPATH=:/home/user/folder/script/_lib/
```

3) `_lib/` contains `lib.py`

4) `python test.py` gives `ImportError: No module named lib`

5) Above error is given on line `from lib import *`

6) If i put my script & library file in same directory ; I don't get any error

Did anyone else encounter this problem?

Comment: What's the `ImportError`? text? what would `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output?

Comment: @cris I am trying to import my own class/python(e.g core_lib.py) from /home/user/folder/script/_lib/ directory-----------------the error which i get is..............ImportError: No module named core_lib--------------------on line ---------------from core_lib import *

Comment: Thanks, and what would the code that i pasted above print out?

Comment: ImportError: No module named core_lib--------------I have updated the question; see point 4, 5, 6

Comment: what would `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output? I assume that you don't run `python` (as an alias) with `-E` commandline argument.

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/home/user_name',
 '/home/user_name/folder/src/test-scripts/_lib',
 ---------------------& other python lib path]